# how to provide test phone numbers for google play store from firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play, google-play-console, one-time-password

I want to provide Google an app access restriction, which in the log in they need to provide a phone number to get the one time password from firebase, and I don't know how to provide test phone number and OTP, I already create test phone number and OTP in firebase console, any solutions?
thank you.